# EFCore error:- ORA-00904: "m"."Id": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

I am working with an application using `asp.net core 2.2` and `efcore database` first approach with `Oracle database`. I am using `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore (2.19.60)` `nuget` package, successfully mapped db model, but when I try to fetch data from `DBContext` , getting error

> ORA-00904: "m"."Id": invalid identifier

Oracle Database version:  Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

code:

```
var fetched = await myDatabaseContext.MyTableVersions.ToListAsync();
```

LinQ is generating following query :

```
SELECT "m"."Id", "m"."MAJORVERSION" FROM "MyTableVersions" "m"
```

Since It's not a correct syntax for PL/Sql query so getting error ORA-00904: "m"."Id": invalid identifier.

Is there any way to fix this error? Thanks.

I have searched on the web and found

> Bug 30352492 - EFCORE: ORA-00904: INVALID IDENTIFIER

but that issue is related to schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is perfectly valid ([db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8a135fe0cdc203f9347d2392776e58ab)), assuming your table looks something like

```
CREATE TABLE "MyTableVersions"
  ("Id"          NUMBER,
   MAJORVERSION  NUMBER)
```

However, I suspect your table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE "MyTableVersions"
  (ID            NUMBER,
   MAJORVERSION  NUMBER)
```

I don't know what the class looks like that you're trying to fetch into, but I suspect it has a field named `Id`. If you can change the name of that field to `ID` (in other words, so that its capitalization matches the capitalization of the related database column) you might find it works then.

Comment: Thanks Bob Jarvis - Reinstate Monica.  My Table script has column Name as ID (uppercase) . while scaffolding table , ODP.Net is creating class with property name as Id. 'entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();'  So, I have mapped this like 'entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID").ValueGeneratedNever(); ' although It's manual effort to renaming Id of every tables but it's fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes are something you should avoid in Oracle world.

Your query:

```
SELECT "m"."Id", "m"."MAJORVERSION" FROM "MyTableVersions" "m"
```

means that column name is **exactly** `Id` (capital `I` followed by `d`). Only if that's really so, you should use double quotes. Otherwise, simply remove them:

```
SELECT m.id, m.MAJORVERSION FROM MyTableVersions m
```

The same goes for the table name - if it was created using mixed case (and you can't do that without double quotes), you'll have to use double quotes and exactly same letter case **always**. Otherwise, don't use them.

Oracle is case-insensitive regarding object and column names and are UPPERCASE by default:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -----------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER

SQL> select table_name, column_name
  2  from user_tab_columns
  3  where table_name = 'TEST';

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TEST                           ID

SQL> insert into test (id) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

But, if you use mixed case with double quotes, then use them always:

```
SQL> create table "teST" ("Id" number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (1);
insert into test (id) values (1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> insert into "test" (id) values (1);
insert into "test" (id) values (1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> insert into "teST" (id) values (1);
insert into "teST" (id) values (1)
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier


SQL> insert into "teST" ("Id") values (1);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

So: first make sure what table and column names really are, then use them appropriately.

Comment: The query in question is being generated by LinQ. I don't know if there's a way for OP to control the name quoting.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems with case-sensitivity, add the option to eliminate EF to add quotes to the generated queries. For instance, if you are using Devart Oracle provider, this is done in the following way:

```
    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        Configure<AbpDbContextOptions>(options =>
        {
            var config = Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.Configuration.OracleEntityProviderConfig.Instance;
            config.Workarounds.DisableQuoting = true;
            ...
        }
    }
```

If you are using official provider - just inherit from `DbCommandInterceptor` (do quotes replacement with empty character in dbCommand in `...Executing` methods), add this interceptor to `DbContextOptionsBuilder` instance.